# How do I always print a message when using go test regardless of success or failure without using verbose mode in golang?

Tags: testing, go

Is there any way to print a message when using `go test` regardless of success or failure without using verbose mode?

I'm generating dummy data and repeatedly running the test and would like to always tell developers the cases covered by the test.

Looking around all the questions I see about this just point to verbose mode and I don't see anything in the godoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't in all cases.

Tests are compiled and executed by the `go test` process. The stdout and stderr are captured by the parent process, and only displayed in verbose mode.

The exceptions are documented in the test code:

```
// stream test output (no buffering) when no package has
// been given on the command line (implicit current directory)
// or when benchmarking.
```

So if you are in the package directory, or running benchmarks, the stdout and stderr will be streamed through the parent process.

Comment: Thanks @JimB! Good to know that I can always get output just running `go test` in the current directory. This will be my default mode and means I could configure a build server to do that.